# How to get the deal information of this JSON?

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

I have this JSON:

```
{
   "status": true,
  "1": {
      "id": "1",
      "deal": "Testing the mobile"
  },
  "2": {
      "id": "2",
      "deal": "Testing"
  },
  "3": {
      "id": "3",
      "deal": "Testing"
  }
}​
```

How can I get the `id` and the `deal`? I'm using **Phonegap** and **jQuery Mobile**.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = {
    "status": true,
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "deal": "Testing the mobile"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "deal": "Testing"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "deal": "Testing"
    }
};

data['1'].id;

data['1'].deal;
```

and so on.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/e2CgK/)**

Using jQuery `$.each()` loop:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    if (key != 'status') {
        alert(val.id);
        alert(val.deal);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/CNn65/5/)**

Using vanilla Javascript

```
for(var key in data){
    if (key != 'status') {
        alert(data[key].id);
        alert(data[key].deal);
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/awVEQ/1/)**